# Python library to open a file handle to Azure Blob Storage object, similar to s3fs library for AWS S3

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage

For AWS S3, there is a Python library called [s3fs](https://github.com/fsspec/s3fs/) that can open file handles to S3 objects.

E.g.

```
import s3fs
s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=True)
with s3.open('my-bucket/my-file.txt', 'rb') as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Is there something similar for Azure Blob Storage?

Comment: Asking for library recommendations is off topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there something similar for Azure Blob Storage?

As of now, the [azure-storage-blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-download-python) Python library can be used to open file handles to Azure Blob Storage objects.

Alternatively, you can use the **`fsspec`** to read the text file from Azure Blob Storage.

**Code:**

```
import fsspec

account_name = "venkat789"
account_key = "zzzzz"

with fsspec.open(f'abfss://<container name>/readfile.txt', account_name=account_name, account_key=account_key) as f:
    data = f.read().decode('utf-8')
    print(data)
```

The above code uses the `fsspec` library to read a file from Azure Blob Storage. It authenticates using the `account_name` and `account_key` variables. The `fsspec.open()` function is used to open the file located at `abfss://sample/readfile.txt`. The contents of the file are read using `f.read()` and converted to a string using `decode()`. Finally, the contents of the file are printed to the console using `print()`.

**Output:**

```
Hello there, Azure Storage. I'm a friendly file ready to be stored in a blob.
```

[image]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions

Comment: Provided an approach with Azure in case Community looking for same.